# How to create a simple table generator for emmet?

Tags: emmet

I want to create an emmet generator that behaves similar to the loremX but to create a html table.

Right now, what I have is simple table snippet that creates one column:

```js
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "ftable": "table>(thead>tr>th)+(tbody>tr>td)"
    }
  }
}
```

So whenever I type `ftable` I'll get:

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But I want more. I'd like to do something like `ftable5`:

And get 5 th's/td's instead.

So the emmet code for this case should be:

```
table>(thead>tr>th*5)+(tbody>tr>td*5)
```

I don't think I can do that with a simple declaration on the snipper. I suppose I should create a generator for that like the one for `loremX`, but I have 0 clue on how to even begin, and honestly I couldn't find much information around. It actually surprises me that such a thing doesn't exist yet (or if it does, let me know), as to generate a HTML table you'd still need to type that much code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your millage may very depending on the tools at hand, but as long as [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is concerned, it has tabstop options https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax

Let's say your snippet definition looks like the one bellow (notice the $1 placeholder)

```json
    "table": {
        "scope": "html",
        "prefix": "table-n",
        "description": "Generates table with n columns",
        "body": "table>(thead>tr>th*$1)(tbody>tr>td*$1)"
    }
```

You would typically

- type the snippet prefix like `table-n`
- click `Enter` to select the snippet
- the snippet is filled in
- cursor for the placeholder blinks
- type the number of expected columns
- click `Tab` to trigger the emmet generation
- the end result should look like this when `$1` is say `3`

[image]

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```